# Overloading "+" for template matrices not working with output stream

Tags: c++, templates, operator-overloading

I'm trying to overload + to add two matrices together and then outputting it immediately. E.g:

```
matrix<int> a, b;
...
cout << a + b << endl;      //doesn't work
matrix<int> c = a + b;      //works
cout << a << endl;          //works

error: cannot bind 'std::ostream {aka std::basic_ostream<char>}' lvalue to 'std::basic_ostream<char>&&'|
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.8.1\include\c++\ostream|602|error:   initializing argument 1 of 'std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::operator<<(std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>&&, const _Tp&) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits<char>; _Tp = matrix<int>]'|
```

I already overloaded << but I'm not sure how to make it work together. Here's what I have so far: (<< works just fine with single matrices)

```
template <typename Comparable>
class matrix
{
    private:
        size_t num_cols_;
        size_t num_rows_;
        Comparable **array_;

    public:
        friend ostream& operator<< (ostream& o, matrix<Comparable> & rhs){
            size_t c = rhs.NumRows();
            size_t d = rhs.NumCols();
            for (int i = 0; i < c; i++){
                for (int j = 0; j < d; j++){
                    o << rhs.array_[i][j] << " ";
                }
                o << endl;
            }
            return o;
        }


        matrix<Comparable> operator+ (matrix<Comparable> & rhs){
            matrix<Comparable> temp(num_rows_,num_cols_);
            for (int i = 0; i < num_rows_; i++){
                for (int j = 0; j < num_cols_; j++){
                    temp.array_[i][j] = array_[i][j] + rhs.array_[i][j];
                }
            }
            return temp;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `a + b` expression yields a prvalue according to the return type declared for `matrix<T>::operator+`:

```
matrix<Comparable> operator+ (matrix<Comparable> & rhs);
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^
```

In turn, `operator<<` expects a modifiable lvalue:

```
friend ostream& operator<< (ostream& o, matrix<Comparable> & rhs);
                                        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^
```

Since `operator<<` is not supposed to modify its argument, you can safely turn it into a `const` lvalue reference (this should work provided that `NumRows()` and `NumCols()` are `const` qualified member functions):

```
friend ostream& operator<< (ostream& o, const matrix<Comparable> & rhs);
                                        ~~~~^
```

Side note: `operator+` should also take its operands as `const` references, and itself should be `const` qualified (if it stays as a member function):

```
matrix<Comparable> operator+ (const matrix<Comparable> & rhs) const;
                              ~~~~^                           ~~~~^
```